# How to display information of a person in a column using a List?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, binding

I am working on a silverlight application using c# and xaml. I have to display information like:

```
SerialNumber  FirstName LastName
s0             ss1       ss1L
s1             ss2       ss2L
```

where     `s0             ss1       ss1L`  and     s`1             ss2       ss2L` must be `List`.

And xaml code to so is bit like this :

```
<UserControl x:Class="DEV_CENTER.ProgramGrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
             xmlns:dataprimitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:ProgramViewModel x:Key="ProgramViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <data:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridPrograms" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ssss1 }" IsReadOnly="True"  DataContext="{StaticResource ProgramViewModel}" >
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Binding="{Binding Path=sss1}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding Path=sss2}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding Path=sss3}" Width="3*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>               
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

**Now how should i code in c# corresponding to achieve what i have asked in ViewModel and Model ?**

Iam sure something has to be like this : Please correct me if i am wrong ?

```
public List<Program> getAllPrograms()
        {
            List<Program> programs = new List<Program>();
            Program p1 = new Program();
            p1.SerialNumber= "ss0";
            p1.FirstName = "ss1";
            p1.LastName= "ss1L";
            Program p2 = new Program();
            p2.SerialNumber= "Program 2";
            p2.FirstName = "ss1";
            p2.LastName= "ss2L";
            programs.Add(p1);
            programs.Add(p2);
            programs.Add(p3);
            return programs;
        }
```

Please help me in achieveing me in my target using mvvm.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What specific results do you want to get?

Comment: @KenHung please see at the top:"SerialNumber  FirstName LastName" (which must be in xaml) and "s0             ss1       ss1L" "s1             ss2       ss2L " must be done using c# using concepts of Mvvm. I mean my Xaml code for hEADING MUST NOT BE CHANGED (which displays Headings) BUT YOU CAN WRITE C# code as you wish to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE II :**

Responding your comment :

1. ObservableCollection has constructor [which accept
   List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
   or `IEnumerable` as parameter.
2. Tested the code in WPF, with slightest modification possible in XAML part and works fine for me. Two rows displayed as in below screen capture image.

[image]

---

Assuming that you have a property `Programs` in `ProgramViewModel` :

```
public ObservableCollection<Program> Programs { get; set; }
```

which is initialized in viewmodel's constructor :

```
Programs = new ObservableCollection<Program>(getAllPrograms());
```

You can bind the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` to `Programs` property, and bind each column to corresponding property of `Program` :

```
<data:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridPrograms" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding Programs}" IsReadOnly="True"  
               DataContext="{StaticResource ProgramViewModel}" >
    <data:DataGrid.Columns>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Binding="{Binding SerialNumber}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}" Width="3*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>               
    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
</data:DataGrid>
```

Note that binding only works with public property instead of field/member, so make sure that SerialNumber, FirstName, and LastName are public properties.

Next step, look into [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged) interface.

**UPDATE :**

```
//viewmodel
public class ProgramViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Program> Programs { get; set; }

    public ProgramViewModel()
    {
        Programs = new ObservableCollection<Program>(getAllPrograms());
    }

    public List<Program> getAllPrograms()
    {
        List<Program> programs = new List<Program>();
        Program p1 = new Program();
        p1.SerialNumber= "ss0";
        p1.FirstName = "ss1";
        p1.LastName= "ss1L";
        Program p2 = new Program();
        p2.SerialNumber= "Program 2";
        p2.FirstName = "ss1";
        p2.LastName= "ss2L";
        programs.Add(p1);
        programs.Add(p2);
        return programs;
    }
}

//model
public class Program
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

//view
<Page.Resources>
    <vm:ProgramViewModel x:Key="ProgramViewModel"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <data:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="gridPrograms" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding Programs}" IsReadOnly="True"  
               DataContext="{StaticResource ProgramViewModel}" >
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="SerialNumber" Binding="{Binding SerialNumber}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="2*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}" Width="3*"></data:DataGridTextColumn>               
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
    </data:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So what i want can not be achieved ? Is there any other alternative ? How will ViewModel code look like ?

Comment: I thought this is what you want? no? Relevant portion of ViewModel already shown above. It should contains `Programs` property.

Comment: i AM SORRY but i am a beginner still i am not able to finish could you please write a small sample having 3 file "ManPage.xaml" "Model.cs" and "ViewModel.cs" which accomplish the same. This would be a big help. Thanks a lottttt.

Comment: Updated the answer with closer to complete code. I haven't really tested the code though

Comment: it's not working .First thing i obsereve may be wrong is getAllPrograms() has return type " List<Program> " in definition whereas "ObservableCollection<Program>" type in call. It just show the Headers but nothing in column below the header. could you please improve it ? thanks..

Comment: Check **UPDATE II** section, the code works fine for me

Comment: could you please also update the code for Model view and Model . How you managed the  INotifyPropertyChanged ? I dont kn ow why it dont work for mze

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50898/discussion-between-user234839-and-har07)